# How do I handle the Intellectual Property theft in office?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, intellectual-property

I have been working in a research organization for the last three years and developed a few innovative methods for practical problems.

While I was busy delivering to customers, my manager asked one of his favorite new employees (she joined just 6 months ago and comes fresh from college) to write a research publication with her as first author and my manager as second author (they did not include my name in the research publication). That publication got accepted and published.

When I came to know about this, I complained but my manager says I am lying. I even contacted the director, but no help from him. Everyone on my team knows that I did that research but nobody is willing to say anything.

What shall I do?

P.S.
I had meeting with director and manager on this issue, meeting ended with manager accusing me of n number of things(that are irrelevant to this issue and were never told to me). final conclusion from meeting - manager will judge who will be author and no one can question that. second thing I must trust manager if I want to work in this organization.

Comment: Since you did it on company time it belongs to the company and is not theft.  It is a lack of recognition.  I don't think you can do anything.

Comment: @Paparazzi it is still theft. Company may have the IP rights but not giving the right authorship is still theft.

Comment: @PagMax Not what I call theft.  Should consult an attorney.

Comment: This is academic misconduct. Nuclear option: Complain to the journal editor. As a result the paper will probably be retracted (if you have at least some proof, like lab journals and such) but you'd need to expect negative consequences for your job. You should at least look for a new job before doing it.

Comment: She wrote the paper without consulting you.  What is it that she used that you produce?  Did she use some of your innovative methods as part of the research of was the paper specifically on some or all of your innovative methods.  Did she use data produced by you?  If so was the data part of the paper?

Comment: OP, you might try searching through the questions on https://academia.stackexchange.com/ . I'm sure a similar situation has been covered there.

Comment: This sounds like a question for Academia SE. However, you need to clarify two things before you ask this question there. (1) What do you mean by _research organization_? An R&D department of a company? Or a Research institute? Or something else? (2) Are you complaining about IP issue? Or you're complaining about ethical issue (plagiarism)?

Comment: @scaaahu I work for R&D department of a company. as mentioned in previous comments I did not get recognition for my work, so I guess it is unethical as well as IP issue.

Comment: In many cases, the IP belongs to the company because you get paid from them. This also depends on the contract between you and the company

Comment: @scaaahu yes, from contract, IP belongs to company. then I guess only problem is unethical use(and i guess its not plagiarism) of someone else's work, or we can say giving recognition to some else for others work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have proof (like research notes, emails, etc) that you worked on the paper, you need to collect that and raise it to either HR or one over your manager. Someone higher up in your company should listen to you.

If you do not get enough support from the company, you can write directly to the publisher and explain your situation. They should ideally either investigate it more or reject the entire paper.

Whatever approach you take, understand that you are accusing your manager of lying. If you go through this till the end, you better win. Otherwise, it can end very ugly for you and you may have to look for alternate employment.

Comment: Even if you do win it could have an ugly end. They aren't likely to fire the boss, and now you are on bad terms with your boss.

Comment: @DavidK  and PagMax , it did end very ugly, with my manager accusing me of n number of things(that are all irrelevant to this issue) in front of director. and final conclusion is, Manager will judge who should be author and I should trust manager if I want to work in organization.                                                                                        thank you guys for suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

You need a paper trail.

If you care about intellectual ownership, you have keep keep a good paper trail and carefully document what you achieve. Every time you think you have some of value or that you care about, it needs to be written down. If you want to make it legally stronger you can notarize or electronically time stamp it. There are web services that offer this at a moderate cost.

In lieu of this, you can try to find e-mails, documents, reports, etc. that clearly show your ownership. Most reasonable companies would accept the "last changed date" or the e-mail header from a the company file server as proof of date of creation.

If you don't have a paper trail: let it go. It's he "he said, she said" situation and no good can come of it

If you do have a paper trail: let it go. Even if you are successful, you will have likely aggravated your management and the company to the point where your future career has been significantly damaged. Getting your name on the paper seems not worth the bother. Be more proactive next time.

Comment: idk about letting it go, we don't know how important this research is, or what the value to the OP might be if being published is. also workplace sounds toxic, OP should not stay there, hence OP might as well consider fighting for recognition.